# Wrong level in TOC for bibliography with sectionbib and memoir

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, bibunits

I have a document using the memoir class, and I use the `bibunits` package to produce chapterwise bibliographies. This produces bibliographies as sections in each chapter, as expected, but in the table of contents, the bibliographies appear as chapters. I would like them to appear as sections there as well. How can I do this?

Here is a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{bibunits}

\begin{document}

\bibliographyunit[\chapter]

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
This is the first chapter with one citation \cite{alonso1992phy}.
\putbib[references]

\end{document}
```

where the `references.bib` file is

```
@book{alonso1992phy,
   author = {Alonso, Marcelo and Finn, Edward J.},
   title = {Physics},
   year = {1992}
}
```

The resulting table of contents looks like this
[image: Table of contents]

Comment: Apparently, `bibunit` does not take care of `memoir` settings. If you use `book` as class, there would be no entry in the ToC at all, by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `memoir` class has by default `\bibsection` defined being `\@memb@bchap`, an starred chapter which is added to the ToC if `\bibintoc` is used.

Redefining `\bibsection` to use `\@memb@bsec` is only a partial workaround, since this would add a numbered section as bibliography unit. 
A slight redefinition of `\@memb@bsec` takes care about this and will use either `\section*` or `\section`, depending on the state of `\ifnumberedbib`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\makeatletter

\newif\ifnumberedbib
\numberedbibfalse % False by default anyway

\AtBeginDocument{%    
\renewcommand{\@memb@bsec}{%
  \ifnumberedbib
  \section{\bibname}
  \else
  \section*{\bibname}%
  \fi
  \bibmark
  \ifnobibintoc\else
  \ifnumberedbib\else
  \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\bibname}%
    \fi
    \fi
    \prebibhook
}

\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\@memb@bsec}
}

\makeatother
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{bibunits}

\begin{document}

\bibliographyunit[\chapter]

\tableofcontents


\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}                           
This is the first chapter with one citation \cite{alonso1992phy}
\putbib[larsreferences]


\section{Second section}                           
This is the first chapter with one citation \cite{alonso1992phy}
\end{document}
```

Comment: One should note that for the real document there's a `global` bibliography -- the `memoir` settings for this usual bibliography should be saved before and restored later on.

Comment: Thanks! That's great, and definitely solves the basic problem. However, I now see that I made my example a little too minimal, because ideally I would like to use this in combination with the natbib package with the numbers option, and that does not work. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @LarsEirikBø: You're complicating the situation. I'll have a look later on

Comment: @LarsEirikBø: See the update -- the culprit is (again ;-))  `memoir` which does some redefinitions for `natbib` in a `\AtBeginDocument{...}` hook. I wrapped another `\AtBeginDocument{...}` around the changes from the original version and it seems to work. However, there might be other `natbib` conditions that are not fit.