# Memoir class and bibunits: avoid a new chapter* for every \putbib

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, bibunits

I am trying to use the memoir class together with `bibunits` (and `natbib`, if that should matter).
Specifically, I am using `\begin{bibunit}` and `\end{bibunit}` to define parts which should receive separate bibliographies, which I then place using `\putbib`, using different .bib-files.

This does work well enough, but with one problem: every instance of `\putbib` seems to insert (possibly among other things) an additional, unnumbered chapter titled "Bibliography", means the page with references has an accordingly large header (and automatically starts a new page, whether I want or not), there is an extra entry in the table of contents, etc. I'd much rather not have this - have `putbib` just produce the list of references and that's it - or if such an insertion is unavoidable, I would at least want the bibliography to be a section (of the current chapter) and not a chapter* of its own.

Here is a minimal example of what I mean:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{bibunits}
\usepackage[round, authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{ecta}
\usepackage{bibunits}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\begin{bibunit}[ecta]
\chapter{First Chapter}
Bla bla.
\putbib
\end{bibunit}

\chapter{Second chapter}
\begin{bibunit}[ecta]
Bla bla.
\putbib
\end{bibunit}
\end{document}
```

Produces the ToC:

[image]

I'd rather have the "Bibliography" entries on the section level; ideally be named "References" instead. Or just get rid of the heading altogether and I'll do it manually is fine too.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se and thanks for including a minimal document with your question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem you're having comes from not using the `sectionbib` option to `bibunits`.  So to have section level bibliographies labelled "References" you need to add the following.

```
\usepackage[sectionbib]{bibunits}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
```

Note that if you are loading `babel` then this renaming must be made by wrapping the `\renewcommand` inside the proper `babel` method. For example, if your main language is set to `english` then you need to use:

```
\addto\extrasenglish{\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}}
```

instead of the simple `\renewcommand` shown above.

However, `memoir` messes with various things, which means that packages like `bibunits` that assume just the basic document classes may not work. So we need to do some more magic, adapting the answer here (which is almost a duplicate):

- [Wrong level in TOC for bibliography with sectionbib and memoir](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/301526/2693)

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{memoir}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Chomsky1981,
    address = {Dordrecht},
    author = {Noam Chomsky},
    publisher = {Foris Publications},
    title = {Lectures on Government and Binding},
    year = {1981}}

@book{Chomsky1986,
    address = {New York},
    author = {Noam Chomsky},
    publisher = {Praeger},
    title = {Knowledge of Language: its nature, origin and use},
    year = {1986}}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[round, authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{bibunits}

\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\newif\ifnumberedbib
\numberedbibfalse % False by default anyway
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%    
\renewcommand{\@memb@bsec}{%
  \ifnumberedbib
  \section{\bibname}
  \else
  \section*{\bibname}%
  \fi
  \bibmark
  \ifnobibintoc\else
  \ifnumberedbib\else
  \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\bibname}%
    \fi
    \fi
    \prebibhook
}

\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\@memb@bsec}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{ecta}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\begin{bibunit}[ecta]
\chapter{First Chapter}
Bla bla.
\citet{Chomsky1981}
\putbib[\jobname]
\end{bibunit}

\chapter{Second chapter}
\begin{bibunit}[ecta]
Bla bla.
\citet{Chomsky1986}
\putbib[\jobname]
\end{bibunit}
\end{document}
```

[image: chapter 1 of code samepl]

Comment: Hey, great, that is awesome and helps me so much. Sorry for missing the related question, which indeed is very similar. If moderators want to close this one, I'd of course understand. Just a small problem with your solution: In my actual document, it does not compile if I copy everything from the MWE. I get an error "Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.(natbib) Press <return> to continue in numerical citation style.". The offending line seems to be `\bibliographyunit[\chapter]` ... (continued)

Comment: If I leave that line out, it compiles, but the sections are then titled "Bibliography" still. Since the minial example compiles nicely for me too, I assume it must have to do with that having empty bibliographies, or some problem in my bibfiles. I'll  try to construct a  MWE with some citations and then post again.

Comment: At any rate, if it is just the title of the section that is off, that'd ok in the worst case. So thank you again already

Comment: @DavidP I see that, and yes, it does seem to be related to empty bibliographies.  I've updated the code with some sample bib items. When I remove the `\bibliographyunit` line, everything works with the titles renamed too.

Comment: Thank you again! It does work in the MWE out of the box for me, in the main document something strange seems to be going on: Some other package must be resetting `\bibname` to Bibliography, but I have no idea which, and there aren't really cadidates that would make sense at first glance. That said, it's a larger project and a messy preamble, maybe I am overlooking something. I just renew `\bibname` at the top of the document once now, and it works. Good enough for me right now. Thank you for your perseverence!

Comment: @DavidP Perhaps you're loading `babel`, in which case you need to use `\addto\extrasenglish{\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}}` (Assuming you've chosen `english` as the main language.)

Comment: Yes that's it! (except in my case it's `\extrasamerican`). Good catch again;  think that's all. Thank you for saving me quite a bit of time with all this.